# how to put an image in the header of dialog window in primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i want to put an image in header of the dialog window in `primefaces`
where i put the red circle i want to put the image over there .

[image]

the css which i have overrided but it didnt works for me

```
.ui-widget-header{
    background:#6BB508 url("resources/theme/img/br.png") !important;
    font-weight: lighter!important;
    text-shadow: none!important;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
    font-size: small!important;
    background-image: url("../img/succ.png")!important; 
}
.ui-dialog-titlebar{

        background-image: url("../img/succ.png")!important; 
    
    
}
```

i tried a lot but i did not find any way
how to do this..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try to include #{request.contextPath} in url images.

For instance,
this code show this result

[image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
    <style>

    .ui-widget-header{
    background:#6BB508 url("#{request.contextPath}/images/chrome.png") !important;
    font-weight: lighter!important;
    text-shadow: none!important;
    color: #FFFFFF!important;
    font-size: small!important;
    background-image: url("#{request.contextPath}/images/chrome.png")!important; 
}
.ui-dialog-titlebar{

        background-image: url("#{request.contextPath}/images/chrome.png")!important; 


}
    </style>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
    <h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">  
    <p:commandButton id="basic" value="Basic" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />  

</h:panelGrid>  

<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Effects" widgetVar="dlg1">  
    <h:outputText value="Image background header window" />  
</p:dialog>  

</h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```